# WinError 183 for MODFLOW executable

Tags: python, flopy

I am attempting to flopy to build a MODFLOW 6 model, using the tutorial I found online from Hatari Labs [1](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/basic-example-of-groundwater-modeling-in-modflow-6-with-python-flopy) as a starting point. When I run the code, I get the following error message.

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:
'C:\Users\User\Documents\Grad School\MODFLOW 6\mf6.1.0\bin\mf6.exe'

with the directory it points being the file path I gave the code as the exe_path for the model and simulation creation. The lines of code I have for writing and running the simulation are just

```
sim.write_simulation()
sim.run_simulation()
```

I assume I need to tell it a new location to write the outputs to, but how do I do that?

Comment: Can you show your full error and give a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Updated the question with the link to the tutorial as well as the file path from the error message, though as I said above, that is just the same file path to what the code is already using to find the exe in the first place.

Comment: Did you try to set your current work directory to the turoial folder by using `os.chdir(path)`. Your output folder is set in the sim package by changing the wariable:  `sim_ws`. In the current script the output will be written to simPath.